# All files in Recycle Bin got restored to the desktop on boot; why?

Tags: windows-7, recycle-bin

Like the title says. Yesterday I started up my laptop and there it was: the  whole desktop, full with old files that I deleted a while ago.

This is the second time I've had this problem. The last time I restored Windows to a previous save and the problem went away, but **what might have caused this to happen?**

I can't seem to find much about this through Google.

Comment: Sounds like Windows used a restoration point and didn't proceed to do something that isn't possible.

Comment: Hi @user329767, and welcome to Super User. I have edited your question to hopefully make it more readable. If you feel I changed your intent, feel free to either revert the edit (click the "edited" link, then click "rollback"), or to [edit] further.

Comment: thats an odd one. have you run chkdsk /f on your disk? I would do so. a corrupted folder could be the culprit.